# Copy data from one table to another table that has the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables here:

table Product:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════╗
║  ProductID  ║  Name      ║  productImageURL   ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ 10          ║  Product 1 ║                    ║
║ 20          ║  Product 2 ║                    ║
║ 30          ║  Product 3 ║                    ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

and table ProductImage

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║  ImageID    ║  ProductID    ║  ImageURL        ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1           ║  10           ║   /imageone.jpg  ║
║ 2           ║  20           ║   /imagetwo.jpg  ║
║ 3           ║  30           ║   /imagethree.jpg║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I would want to copy Image url from ProductImage table to Product table with coresponding Product ID. How do I do that in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` in your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE p
    SET p.productImageURL = i.ImageURL
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductImage i
    ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: Or use outer join / outer apply, when  you have a few images per product

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as that of Felix but cleaner SQL. Works in MySql.

```
UPDATE Product p, ProductImage i
    SET p.productImageURL = i.ImageURL
WHERE i.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

Comment: Clean to read I mean. I am using this script to sync tables in real time in MySql, so I know that his script really works. So if you don't mind please revert your vote.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is tagged SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE product p
SET p.product = (
    SELECT i.ImageURL
    FROM ProductImage i
    WHERE i.ProductID = p.ProductID
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).